# Need a tool for PostgreSQL monitoring on Windows

Tags: postgresql, profiling, monitoring

I have Postgres running on Windows and I'm trying to investigate the strange behaviour: There are 17 postgres processes, 8 out of those 17 consume ~300K memory each.

- Does anybody know what such behavior is coused by?
- Does anybody know about a tool to investigate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> 8 out of those 17 consume ~300K memory
>   each.

Are you 110% sure? Windows doesn't know how much memory is used from the shared buffers. Each proces could use just a few kb's and using the shared memory together with the other processes.

What problem do you have? Using memory is not a problem, memory is made to use. And 300KB each, that's just a few MB all together, if each proces is realy using 300KB.

And don't forget, PostgreSQL is a multi proces system. That's also why it scales so easy on multi core and multi processor systems.

Comment: - I've taken memory consuming numbers from the "Mem Usage" column of Windows Task Manager. Do you mean that it is not adequate for processes using shared memory?
- I understand that PostgreSQL is a multi-process system, but 17 processes!?

Comment: The "Mem Usage" column of Windows Task Manager doesn't know anything about shared memory, it's just an estimate. 17 processes isn't that much, sounds like a couple of basic processes (like the postmaster and auto_vacuum) and some connections from applications. When you have 50 connections, you will see more than 50 processes. Nothing to worry about, this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

See pgAdmin: http://www.pgadmin.org/

Answer (score 0):

A tool for analyzing *output* from postgresql can be found at http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/

> pgFouine is a PostgreSQL log analyzer used to generate detailed reports from a PostgreSQL log file. pgFouine can help you to determine which queries you should optimize to speed up your PostgreSQL based application.

I don't think you can find out why you have alot of processes running, but if you feel that it might be because of database usage, this tool might help you find a cause.